# How to add file in NSIS from headers

Tags: nsis

### main_installer.nsi

This includes the header file that will install common files:

```
!include "C:\dir1\dir2\installer_helper_1.nsh"
```

And calls the function/macro:

```
${helper_1} $0
```

Where `$0` is the return value indicating success.

### installer_helper_1.nsh

This header file contains the function/macro `${helper_1}` to add common files.

This function/macro contains the line:

```
File "C:\dir1\dir2\CommonFile1.txt"
```

How can I change this line such that the directory CommonFile1.txt is located in can be relative to the header file?

```
File "CommonFile1.txt"
```

The above line will not work as the compiler will look for the file in the same director as main_installer.nsi. I want the equivalent relative path such that it will look in the directory where installer_helper_1.nsh is located.

Answer (score 0):

NSIS 3 has a `${__FILEDIR__}` define you can use:

```
File "${__FILEDIR__}\CommonFile1.txt"
```

Comment: What about for NSIS 2.51?

Comment: Obviously if I had a good solution for v2.x I would have posted it. You probably have to add a !define in your .nsi that the .nsh can reference.